# Quali sono i verbi di seconda coniugazione che non terminano in "-ere"?

Tags: verbs, infinitive

Ricordo di aver imparato alle scuole medie che i verbi italiani si dividono in tre modelli di coniugazione a seconda della desinenza dell'infinito presente: i verbi in *-are* nella prima coniugazione, i verbi in *-ere* nella seconda e i verbi in *-ire* nella terza coniugazione.

Recentemente però ho scoperto che anche *fare* e *dire*, nonstante la regola di cui sopra, vengono classificati come verbi di seconda coniugazione, il che a ripensarci non sembra neanche tanto strano considerando le voci degli altri modi verbali.

Esistono altri verbi di seconda coniugazione che non terminano in *-ere* all'infinito presente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esistono diversi verbi di seconda coniugazione che non terminano in *-ere*.

Ad esempio, *porre* ed altri come *deporre* e *proporre*,  *produrre*, *ridurre*, *trarre*.

Si tratta quasi sempre di verbi derivanti dal latino, che terminavano in *-ere* ed appartenevano dunque a pieno titolo alla seconda coniugazione. Esempi: *pōnĕre* che è diventato *porre*.

Comment: Una rapida ricerca qui https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbi_irregolari_italiani dà i tre casi più comuni: *addurre*, *trarre* e il già menzionato *porre*, più tutti i verbi che si coniugano secondo il loro modello (questi sono i verbi derivati da composti dei latini *ducĕre*, *trahĕre* e *ponĕre* rispettivamente)

Comment: Non compreso *redarre*! `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: Per "redarre" si intende un errore? (che dovrebbe essere "redigere"?)

Comment: @Charo Sì, certo! Ma è un errore piuttosto comune. `:(`